# Difference of dates as minutes in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongo db schema

```js
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("52aaea01701054a10a002212"),
        "type" :"go_to_page", 
        "params" : 
        { 
            "page" : "users"
        },
        "created" :ISODate("2013-12-30T05:30:24.324Z")
    }
```

The "page" can have any of the four values like profile, event, people and shout. So if a user jumps from people page to profile page i can save them into the mongo database and now i can have the log of the activities of the user. Now i have to find the exact time in minutes that the user spent on each of the above mentioned four pages.

is there any method in mongo which takes input two given dates and and returns the timespan between the two dates in minutes. i.e. if i give the data as 2014-04-29 23:50:00 and 2014-04-30 00:00:00 then it should return 10 because it is 10  minutes between the two given dates. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with the aggregation framework but I sense, using the force, that this would not be a good method for you unless this is while querying using the aggregation framework. Otherwise something like this is normally better done client side

Comment: Could you actually explain you use case? What are you trying to do? Are you trying to accumulate items by 10 minute periods? Are you trying to show the intervals between consecutive documents? That is the detail missing from your question.

Comment: actullay this is the structure of my mongo db schema {
 "user" : ObjectId("52aaea01701054a10a002212"),
 "type" : "go_to_page",
 "params" : {
  "page" : "users"
 },
 "created" : ISODate("2013-12-30T05:30:24.324Z")
}
in the pages filed there can be four variables like shout,events, people and profile. now i want to find out that on an average how much time did a particular user spent on the people page, profile page, event page and the shout page in minutes

Comment: I am assuming there is a way to tell when a user left a page? Without that you cannot really say how long as user spent on a page

Comment: Edit your question and give as much information as you can. Using comments is not the right place for this. You seem to want some sort of funnel analysis, so describe that in your question.

Comment: i have edited my question and given the full description of the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried following code in mongo 2.4.8 and found when you take difference between two dates it returns a result in millisecond,then wrote following function to get data in minutes.
Here I have assumed you have two date fields in your document 'entered'(when user entered) and 'left'(when user left) and finally you calculate the difference in minutes and  store 'timespent'  in the same document

```js
 db.collectioName.find().forEach(function(d){
    //you can use Math.ceil or Math.floor
    d.timespent=Math.round((d.visited-d.left)/60000); 
    db.collectioName.save(d);
 });
```

Hope it helps